# iOS networking technology for synchronizing user activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

I'm a newbie to iOS, and I'm somewhat lost in the sea of networking libraries available.

I'm interested a library that will allow me to:

- discover other users using the application nearby
- send activity (for example the coordinates of where the user last touched the screen)
- receive activity (for example the coordinates where another user last touched the screen)
- send/receive activity with relatively low latency
- not require a command and control server of some sort to coordinate all this if possible

Is there one library that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the Multipeer Connectivity framework:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html

It lets you construct peer to peer connections over bluetooth, cell, wifi, and peer-to-peer wifi.   I'm going to start investigating this myself very soon so feel free to stay in touch if you want to trade experiences.

Comment: Thanks Neal, this looks like most of what I was looking for.  Lets stay in touch about it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid a server side in this case if you want to

- discover other users using the application nearby

Unless you use technology like bluetooth? Otherwise, AFNetworking is a high level, easy to use framework with very good documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen AFNetworking, good background that its somewhat of a standard